# Not work append(jQuery) in the code

Tags: javascript, jquery, codeigniter, caching

I use codeigniter but my JS code isn't working! Can anyone guide me?

[**Example**](http://binboy.gigfa.com/test)

```
<select name="tour_name" style="display: none; ">
    <option disabled="disabled" value="">select</option>
    <option>hello</option>
    <option>hi</option>
    <option>what</option>
    <option>how</option>
</select>
<div id="#tour_name">
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('select[name="tour_name"]').change(function () {
        $('#tour_name').empty();
        var $val = $(this).val();
        $(this).hide();
        $('#tour_name').hide().fadeIn('slow').append('<b>' + $val + '</b>')
        $('#tour_name b').click(function () {
            $('#tour_name').empty();
            $('select[name="tour_name"]').fadeIn('slow')();
        })
    })
});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your HTML is incorrect. Replace

```
<div id="#tour_name">
```

by

```
<div id="tour_name">
```

Answer (score 5):

change

```
<div id="#tour_name">
```

to

```
<div id="tour_name">
```

when creatig an id to element . consider these things

> Specifies a unique id for an element.
>
> Naming rules:
>
> ```
> Must begin with a letter A-Z or a-z
> Can be followed by: letters (A-Za-z), digits (0-9), hyphens ("-"),
> ```
>
> and underscores ("_")
>       In HTML, all values are case-insensitive